# R merge two different time series with same date

Tags: python, r, pandas, merge, zoo

I have csv file with data. [Link is here.](http://www.filedropper.com/q1)  Granularity of time series is 5 min for year 2013. However, values are missing for some time stamps.

I want to create a time series with 5 minute interval with value zero for time stamps which are missing.

Please advise how to do this either in Pandas or Python

Comment: Do you want a solution in pandas or R? That's the #1 thing to make clear here.

Comment: I am ok with either solution

Comment: ok, you need to do the following if you want to get helpful responses: 1) be very clear about that upfront in the question, 2) tag this question properly, and 3) include copy/pastable examples that people can use to mess around with your data. Doesn't have to be all the data -- just the minimum amount needed to demonstrate the concepts

Comment: Paul, I think I did all that you asked. I did mention that "How can I merge TS1 and TS2 either using zoo or Python-Pandas?" and my tables are copy/pastable examples. Please let me know, if anything is missing. Thank you

Comment: Not really. You mostly posted output that isn't very useful and your tags don't mention python, R, or zoo (I'll add them). See my response for a what a self-contained, copy-pastable example looks like.

Answer (score 0):

In pandas, you just join on the index:

```
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import pandas

ts1_string = StringIO("""\
V1,V2
01/01/2013 00:05:00,10
01/01/2013 00:10:00,6
01/01/2013 00:15:00,10
01/01/2013 00:25:00,8
01/01/2013 00:30:00,11
01/01/2013 00:35:00,7""")

ts2_string = StringIO("""
V1,V2
2013-01-01 00:00:00,0
2013-01-01 00:05:00,0
2013-01-01 00:10:00,0
2013-01-01 00:15:00,0
2013-01-01 00:20:00,0
2013-01-01 00:25:00,0""")

ts1 = pandas.read_csv(ts1_string, parse_dates=True, index_col='V1')
ts2 = pandas.read_csv(ts2_string, parse_dates=True, index_col='V1')

# here's where the join happens
# (suffixes deal with overlapping column names)
ts_joined = ts1.join(ts2, rsuffix='_ts1', lsuffix='_ts2')

# and finally
print(ts_joined.head())
```

Which gives:

```
                     V2_ts2  V2_ts1
V1                                 
2013-01-01 00:05:00      10       0
2013-01-01 00:10:00       6       0
2013-01-01 00:15:00      10       0
2013-01-01 00:25:00       8       0
2013-01-01 00:30:00      11     NaN
```

Comment: Hi Paul, Thank you for answer. Can you pls use TS1 and TS2. You have generated random numbers. But I already have TS1. I think problem is with datetime syntax in TS1 and TS2.

Comment: can you provide some code that will generate your TS1 and TS2? (@Chandra)

Comment: @Chandra how's that? In general, people are only willing to put slightly less work into the solution as you are into the question.

Comment: Copy TS1 into "TS1.csv" file and in python -- dat=pd.read_csv("TS1.csv") index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2013-01-01 00:00', end='2014-01-01 00:00', freq='5 min') df=pd.DataFrame(index=index)  TS1.to_csv("Q1.csv",date_format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df.to_csv("Q2.csv",date_format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")df=pd.DataFrame(index=index)

Comment: @Chandra *that* is what should be in your question! (delete your comment once it is)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64452/discussion-between-chandra-and-paul-h).